# How to count of number of rows in Criteria Api

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria-api

What I'm trying to do is count rows fit to typed criteria (I need to warn user that lookup will spend some time   `x rows * (estimated time for one row)` ,  my code looks like :

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<TrackingDAO> p = criteria.from(TrackingDAO.class);
criteria.select(qb.count(criteria
            .from(TrackingDAO.class)));
/* my stuff with criteria */ 
TypedQuery<Long> q = em.createQuery(criteria);
setCounterOfLookUpResults(q.getSingleResult());
```

Class is working fine , until I got results, they are totally weird  like e.g 56432 and I'm expecting e.g 430 .

Can somebody tell me how to "ping" database and ask how many rows it's going to provide me before I'm fetching that rows ?

Comment: You're code looks fine to me, are you sure about your criteria and joins?

Comment: My criteria looks like : 

criteria.where(qb.and(qb.like(p.<String> get(entityname), param) ,
    qb.between(p.<Date> get("startTime"), getFromTime(),
     getToTime()),
     qb.equal(p.<String> get("status"), getStatus())
    ));


Now I tried again and Results of code above was 13112 while the final effect was only 2 rows ! no idea where is the problem

Comment: criteria.select(qb.count(p.get(TrackingDAO_.id))); as suggested by Roman C worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Projections` to get row count from criteria

```
  criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
  return Integer.parseInt(criteria.list().get(0).toString());
```

or

```
criteria.select(qb.count(p.get(TrackingDAO_.id)));
```

Comment: thanks, for quick answer but the method setProjection(...) does not working with CriteriaQuery, I would like to avoid changing all criterias to Criteria class from CriteriaQuery

Comment: Second method works with 'criteria' being belonging to CriteriaQuery class. It was equivalent to native sql query as: SELECT count(id) FROM my_table WHERE (parama < something) AND paramb = something AND (....);

Answer (score 1):

All looks like count method in my case returns every single action during performing my code , I assume by numbers like : 6949360 when query returns 430 results , and "only" 1131 when I have 1 result

Answer (score 0):

Most databases don't know what you're going to ask for before you ask for it depending on your WHERE clause.  So the most generic way of doing this would be to write a method that takes your table, and your where clause and does a count(*) against it and tells you how many rows would match your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Projections to get the row count

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
int count = Integer.valueOf(criteria.uniqueResult());
```